# bash script curl upload files to php page

Tags: linux, bash, php, curl, upload

I am not sure that I am posting on the correct forum. I am working with Linux Centos 7 and I write a bash script which take all files with txt extension from a directory to upload them to the server with php.
The bash script seems to find all files inside the directory but it upload only one file and at the end of the process my php page is deleted.

My bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh
for filename in $(find /home/rico/mywebsite/ -maxdepth 1 -name \*.txt )
do
echo ${filename}
curl -O -X POST -F 'avatar=@'${filename} http://localhost/ions/uploadTXT.php
done;
```

and my php page is written like that:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$dir = '/opt/lampp/htdocs/ions/upload/';
$filename = basename($_FILES['avatar']['name']); //this var is for the parameter past into input field and used for $handle

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'], $dir . $filename)) {
}
?>
```

Comment: Does it `echo` all filenames correctly? I assume yes because you said that the "script seems to find all files". If you add a line `echo $?` (= "print return value of previous command") below the `curl` command to your script, what does it output?

Comment: `echo ${filename}` displayed correctly all files contained in the directory ==> . `echo $?` output `0`. Below the curl command I don't have any errors in output it just shows: `  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  360M    0     0  100  360M      0   346M  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  346M
`